# Devise redirects to /users after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, erb

In my application controller I have

```
protect_from_forgery

layout :layout_by_resource

def layout_by_resource
  if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user && action_name == 'new'
    "signin"
  else
    "application"
  end
end
```

So the devise views like sign in, sign up, forgot password etc use that layout.

For some reason, on the sign up and forgot password pages, if I were to get an error, it'd redirect to `/users` (if sign up page was wrong) and `/users/password` if the forgot password page was wrong. On the sign in page however, it just displays the errors like normal.

In my `signin` layout content I have:

```
<% flash.each do |key,msg| %>
    <div class="message" id="<%= key %>">
        <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<&= yield %>
```

For the sign in view, I have:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource, :url => session_path(resource)) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit 'Sign in', :class => "button" %>
  <p><%= f.check_box :remember_me %><%= f.label :remember_me, "Stay Signed In" %></p>
<% end %>
```

For the sign up view, I have:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource, :url => registration_path(resource)) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %></p>
  <p><%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit 'Sign up', :class => "button" %>
<% end %>
```

And for the forgot password view I have:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Reset", :class => "button" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

### Update

Here's what I've overridden in my routes for devise:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/account" => "devise/registrations#edit"
  get "/signin" => "devise/sessions#new", :as => "signin"
  get "/signout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => "signout"
end
```

Comment: Have you overridden any of the routes used by devise ?

Comment: See the update I just made